# XSL Transform to output a number of embedded XSL stylesheets

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing

I wish to write an XSL transform that outputs a number of embedded stylesheets inside TEMPLATE elements (the stylesheet collection is processed downstream by another component that extracts the required one and applies it). So what I want to produce as a result of the transform is an XML file containing something like this:

[structure of the desired XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTTI1.png)

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<TEMPLATEDATA xmlns="http://www.sanjay.com/appname" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <TEMPLATE name="addFocus" operation="Add">
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0">
      <xsl:template match="/">
        <STRATEGICFOCUS />
      </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
  </TEMPLATE>

    
  <TEMPLATE name="addOrg" operation="Init">
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:app="http://www.sanjay.com/myapp">
      <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
      <xsl:param name="Name"></xsl:param>
      <xsl:template match="*">
          <CONTENT>
              <NAME><xsl:value-of select="$Name"/></NAME>
          </CONTENT>
      </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
  </TEMPLATE>
  
</TEMPLATEDATA>
```

I want to produce this output by defining a XSL transform like so (ignore the input XML that I am transforming as it's not important):

[desired transform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEuLC.png)

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns="http://www.sanjay.com/myapp">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <TEMPLATEDATA>
            <xsl:call-template name="template1" />
            <xsl:call-template name="template2" />
        </TEMPLATEDATA>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="template1">
        <TEMPLATE name="addFocus" operation="Add">
            <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0">
                <xsl:template match="/">
                    <STRATEGICFOCUS />
                </xsl:template>
            </xsl:stylesheet>
        </TEMPLATE>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="template2">
        <TEMPLATE name="addOrg" operation="Init"
            <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:app="http://www.sanjay.com/myapp">
                <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
                <xsl:param name="Name"></xsl:param>
                <xsl:template match="*">
                    <CONTENT>
                        <NAME>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$Name"/>
                        </NAME>
                    </CONTENT>
                </xsl:template>
            </xsl:stylesheet>
        </TEMPLATE>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get an XSL parse error for the stylesheet saying that the inner xsl:stylesheet is invalid becasue it cannot be the child of a TEMPLATE element. Can anyone tell me what I have to do to get around this? I know I can probably embed the inner stylsheets in CDATA sections but I'd prefer not to do that.

sanjay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want to use a namespace alias https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#element-namespace-alias for the result elements e.g.

```
 <xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="axsl" result-prefix="xsl"/>
```

with `xmlns:axsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform-alias"` declared and used for e.g.

```
<xsl:template name="template1">
    <TEMPLATE name="addFocus" operation="Add">
        <axsl:stylesheet version="1.0">
            <axsl:template match="/">
                <STRATEGICFOCUS />
            </axsl:template>
        </xasl:stylesheet>
    </TEMPLATE>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Great thanks Martin. I think that will solve my problem.